# Custom HtmlHelper Renders Text and not Markup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have written a basic HtmlHelper. Here's a test I wrote that simplifies what I was doing and to provide self assurance that it is happening when I use `StringBuilder` and `TagBuilder` objects:

```
public static string HelloWorld(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var builder = new TagBuilder("span");
    builder.InnerHtml = "Hello, " + name + "!";
    sb.Append(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    sb.Append("<br/>");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The output for this control encodes the string so I see the following:
`<span>Hello, Jason!</span><br/>`

In my view, I'm using the following: `@Html.HelloWorld("Jason")`

Any ideas what I can be doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Razor engine escapes HTML by default in any strings that it renders. If you change the return type to `IHtmlString`, this won't happen.

```
public static IHtmlString HelloWorld(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name)
    ...
    return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to set the method return type to HtmlString too.

Answer (score 3):

Your static method must be `HtmlString` instead of `string`, and you must return the `HtmlString(sb.ToString());`

```
public static HtmlString HelloWorld(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var builder = new TagBuilder("span");
    builder.InnerHtml = "Hello, " + name + "!";
    sb.Append(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    sb.Append("<br/>");

    return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to cast my return as an HtmlString as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AppendFormat`  instead of `Append`

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var builder = new TagBuilder("span");
    builder.InnerHtml = "Hello, " + name + "!";
    sb.AppendFormat(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    sb.AppendFormat("<br/>");

    return sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for the year 2018 working with .Net Core 2

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.IO;

public static IHtmlContent HelloWorld(this IHtmlHelper html, string name)
{
    var span = new TagBuilder("span");
    span.InnerHtml.Append("Hello, " + name + "!");

    var br = new TagBuilder("br") {TagRenderMode = TagRenderMode.SelfClosing};

    string result;

    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        span.WriteTo(writer, System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default);
        br.WriteTo(writer, System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default);
        result = writer.ToString();
    }

    return new HtmlString(result);
}
```